# Screen is returning the message: “Must be connected to a terminal.”

Tags: linux, display, java, python

I am running a Java program, and with the Java program, I run a Python script. The python script (with subprocess.Popen) runs the command

```
screen -x hg1 -X stuff "jsp sign edit status1 2 test line $(printf '\r')"
```

...but when it does that, it retuns the error

```
Must be connected to a terminal.
```

I tried doing many things, including doing a bunch of switches (e.g. -dm, -d, -m, etc.), but none of them work.

How do I make screen stuff a command without giving me that error?

Comment: Maybe you can try tmux? I'm not sure if it will work differently, but you can try it.

Comment: What you're actually trying to accomplish? To me it sounds like using screen/tmux is just added complexity as you don't state any reason why your commands should be run through screen.

Comment: @SamiLaine I'm trying to send a command to a Minecraft server that is running in a screen session.

Comment: My suspicion is that your Python call is flawed somehow. Does `subprocess.call(['screen', '-x', 'hg1', '-X', 'stuff', 'jsp sign edit status1 2 test line \r'])` not work? Calling shell from Python called from Java sounds like you have a lot you want to simplify anyway.

Comment: Have you tried to force the allocation of a terminal by putting something like `ssh -t localhost` before the `screen` command?

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that you don't have an interactive shell terminal session from inside the python script; there's no tty allocated. You might want to try the python `pty` module.

If you already had an interactive terminal, you could try `script /dev/null`, then screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
screen -dm -x hg1 -X stuff "jsp sign edit status1 2 test line $(printf '\r')"
```

You can find more infos here: http://www.computerhope.com/unix/screen.htm